# Can't get the src attribute of an img using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to get the src attribute of an image but it just returns a completely different thing.

This is the img element:
[element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yEf1.png)

This is the code I'm using to scrape it (it returns other attributes perfectly fine so I'm sure I'm getting the right element):

```
pic = hrefs.a.div.div.span.img.get('src')
```

And the output of the pic variable is this:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape src attribute from google with beautiful soup only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64439020/scrape-src-attribute-from-google-with-beautiful-soup-only)

Comment: @MubarakSalley I pretty much get this error, not much help:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), but my guess would be that the page initially has that as a placeholder, and then the srcset and src attributes are added by javascript.  You should try printing the element you have to see what is available, and if it differs from what you see in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your example from the screenshot (not great to reproduce), did you try this?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="random_class">
    <img alt="Air Jordan 1" src="https://cdn.myikas.com/images/blablabla"/>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('img')['src'])
```

output

```
https://cdn.myikas.com/images/blablabla
```

Answer (score 0):

am using the following html document

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>From wikipedia</p>
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
        //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the above is the html i am scraping

this is the image

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
        //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

and this is the part we need to decode

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
        //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

so you need to get the string after the last comma from your `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`

```py
src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
src.split(",")[-1] # This will get the last sequence of text after a comma
# OUTPUT : R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

Ok so now you have the string ( am not going to use your string because when i tried it i didnt see an image, i will use the string in the html code above ).

This is how you go about decoding it now in python 3.10.4

```py
import base64
image_base64_string = """iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
        //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="""

image_decoded = base64.b64decode( image_base64_string)

# Now its time to save the image
myfile = open("mygif.gif", "wb+")
myfile.write(image_decoded)
myfile.close()
# You should be able to see the file and open it
```